# Is it possible to filter out outliers that overlap based on time variable in R?

Tags: r, filter, data-cleaning, outliers

How do I delete outliers by checking for an overlap between ID column and date/time columns with`filter()`?

For example, rows with ID =1 overlap in time as shown in the first 2 rows below,thus need to be deleted.

| ID | Time start | Time end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-03-16 10:40:00 | 2015-03-16 11:10:00 |
| 1 | 2015-03-16 10:50:00 | 2015-03-16 10:59:00 |
| 2 | 2015-03-16 10:40:00 | 2015-03-16 10:45:00 |
| 1 | 2015-03-16 11:20:00 | 2015-03-16 11:28:56 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to remove any time overlaps within a group. Please test it with more data to see if it does what you want. I only tried the small sample below.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(slider)

tribble(
  ~id, ~start, ~end,
  1, "2015-03-16 10:40:00", "2015-03-16 11:10:00",
  1, "2015-03-16 10:50:00", "2015-03-16 10:59:00",
  1, "2015-03-16 11:09:00", "2015-03-16 11:11:00",
  2, "2015-03-16 10:40:00", "2015-03-16 10:45:00",
  1, "2015-03-16 11:20:00", "2015-03-16 11:28:56",
  1, "2015-03-16 11:27:00", "2015-03-16 11:30:56",
  2, "2015-03-16 10:44:00", "2015-03-16 11:45:00"
) |>
  mutate(
    start = ymd_hms(start, tz = Sys.timezone()),
    end = ymd_hms(end, tz = Sys.timezone())
  ) |>
  arrange(id, start, end) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(
    roll_start = slide_vec(start, min, .before = Inf),
    roll_end = slide_vec(end, max, .before = Inf),
    overlap = if_else((start >= lag(roll_start) & start <= lag(roll_end)) |
      (end >= lag(roll_start) & end <= lag(roll_end)), "yes", "no")
  ) |>
  filter(overlap == "no" | is.na(overlap)) |> 
  select(- c(starts_with("roll_"), overlap))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id start               end                
#>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1     1 2015-03-16 10:40:00 2015-03-16 11:10:00
#> 2     1 2015-03-16 11:20:00 2015-03-16 11:28:56
#> 3     2 2015-03-16 10:40:00 2015-03-16 10:45:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>